# homotopy via isotopy

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Is it possible to realize a homotopy between two vector bundles (which are sub-bundles of the tangent bundle) over the same base $B$ as induced by an ambient isotpy? In other words, assume $X_t $ is a continuous family of sub-bundles of $TB$ of the same rank, connecting two sub-bundles $X_0$ and $X_1$ over base $B$. Is it possible to find an isotopy $\phi_t:M \to M $ so that $(\phi_t)_\star X_0=X_t$?

Comment: What is your definition of "continuous family of vector bundles"? Are the $X_t$'s just pullbacks of $X_0$ along some homotopy $f_t \colon B \to B$?